# Stripe payment not showing in Stripe dashboard after successful payment

Tags: django, django-views, stripe-payments

I’m facing an issue with Stripe integration with my Django e-commerce website. Even though I followed the Stripe docs of accepting online payments, so when i open the checkout and complete the payment form, I get redirected to the success page. However, upon checking the Stripe dashboard for the payment, they are not showing. Also, I’m sending all the products at once and I’m loading the Stripe JS in my checkout. I'm not sure if I've set it up correctly. Is my integration complete?

```
@login_required(login_url='core:login_register')
def checkout(request):
    user_profile = request.user.userprofile
    cart = get_object_or_404(Cart, user=user_profile)
    total_price = cart.calculate_total_price()
    has_existing_billing_address = Address.objects.filter(user=user_profile).exists()
    form = CheckoutForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        order, _ = Checkout.objects.get_or_create(user=user_profile, cart=cart)
        default_billing_address = form.cleaned_data['use_default_billing_address']

        if default_billing_address:
            billing_address = Address.objects.filter(user=user_profile, default=True).first()
            order.billing_address = billing_address
        else:
            new_billing_address = Address(
                user=user_profile,
                street_address=form.cleaned_data['street_address'],
                apartment_address=form.cleaned_data['apartment_address'],
                zip_code=form.cleaned_data['zip_code'],
                country=form.cleaned_data['country'],
                default=True
            )
            new_billing_address.save()
            order.billing_address = new_billing_address

        order.save()
        payment_method = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_method')

        if payment_method:
            return redirect('core:payment', payment_method='card')

    context = {
        'total_price': total_price,
        'form': form,
        'has_existing_billing_address': has_existing_billing_address,
        'STRIPE_API_KEY': settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
    }
    return render(request, 'checkout.html', context)
```

```
@login_required(login_url='core:login_register')
def payment(request, payment_method):
    user_profile = request.user.userprofile
    cart = get_object_or_404(Cart, user=user_profile)
    billing_address_exists = Address.objects.filter(user=user_profile).exists()
    cart_items = cart.items.all()
    if not billing_address_exists:
        return redirect('core:checkout')
    
    line_items = [{
        'price_data': {
            'currency': 'usd',
            'product_data': {
                'name': item.product.title,
            },
            'unit_amount': int(item.product.price * 100),
        },
        'quantity': item.quantity,
    } for item in cart_items]

    try:
            session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                payment_method_types=[payment_method],
                line_items=line_items,
                mode='payment',
                customer_creation = 'always',
                success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('core:success')),
                cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('core:cancel')),
            )

            return redirect(session.url)
    
    except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
        return HttpResponse(f"Stripe Error: {str(e)}")
    
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

**UPDATE**

I added the webhook from the Stripe documentation, which listens to the request body. but after going through the Stripe checkout and filling in the form, my webhook doesn't provide any response, neither "checkout.session.completed" nor any errors

Comment: Have you checked your Dashboard request log? https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs You should find the request created the Checkout Session, and the event `checkout.session.completed` there. You can also add some debug log after creating the session, i.e. `print(session.id)`

Comment: @orakaro Well, I just checked, and the status code was 200 but for the POST request, I couldn't find the 'checkout.session.completed' event. Also, am I handling the line items correctly? I suspect the request query parameters might be incomplete.

{
  "limit": "10",
  "active": "true",
  "expand": {
    "0": "data.product"
  }
}

Comment: Did it give you a Checkout Session object in the POST response? Do you see another POST request to `POST /v1/payment_pages/cs_test_xxx` after you paid it in the browser?

Comment: Nope, it did not. All it gave me were query parameters